# Incorrect syntax near '.' , not sure why?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Parse Error ---> Why? (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   9.00.4035.00)

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

This is my code:

```
USE master;
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle);
GO
```

Second Method

> Msg 321, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   "plan_handle" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

Code:

```
USE master;
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle);
GO
```

Comment: Executes fine at my end. Do you have VIEW SERVER STATE permission on server?

Comment: i have that permission set to GRANT and i'm logged in as sa.

Comment: Maybe this will help - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8d30c2fa-3990-4bda-80e4-93a213be952a/help-with-sysdmexecqueryplan-dmf?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

The database was upgraded from Server 2000 to 2005.  During installation and configuration the [default compatibility level is retained](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259649%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). In this case the compatibility level was set to 80.

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel 'master', '90'
GO
```

Server was set to 80....duhh

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Actually, for the OP, it *does* answer the question because it's the OP that posted the answer. It does not make for a good answer to the question though as the problem is somewhat outside the scope of it.